# How to stop background music playing from a different class playing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

Ive set a music track to play within the ViewController.h and .m files as shown below. I want to stop this when a new scene is loaded. (.h):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{

    AVAudioPlayer *startingMusic;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *startingMusic;

@end
```

and then .m

```
@synthesize startingMusic;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:musicTrack ofType:@"mp3"];
    startingMusic=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
    startingMusic.delegate=self;
    startingMusic.numberOfLoops=-1;
    [startingMusic play];
}
```

I then try and stop this from playing when the new scene loads is a different class called PlayLevel.m in an init method using this code.

```
ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[test.startingMusic stop];
```

However the music just continues to play when the new seen loads. Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason the code you've written won't stop the music is because you're creating entirely new `ViewController` when you call `init`. You want to keep a reference to the initial `ViewController` or I've answered with what I would suggest is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way around, you should really be stopping the music within `ViewController` and not from another class. ViewController should be self contained where ever possible.

How are you loading the 2nd scene? I imagine you're using a Segue?

If you are using a segue you can override the function `-prepareForSegue` which is a `UIViewController` function. Within `-prepareForSegue` stop the music then.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Stop Music
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using sprite kit to load the new scenes so when loading a new scene the code looks like this:

    SKScene * scene = [[PlayLevel alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size level:1];

Comment: Ahh I'm unfamiliar with SpriteKit, I image you call `SKScene * scene = [[PlayLevel alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size level:1];` from within `ViewController`? Can you stop the music the line before you call the above line?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] init];` you created the new ViewController instance, it's mean you now have two ViewController's objects in the memory.

What you really need to do is call `stop` on your current one.

If you want to stop music from another controller which has no connection to your `ViewController` you can try doing this via notifications.

For example:

in your `ViewController.h` file, after imports:

```
static NSString * const kStopMusicNotificationName = @"kStopMusicNotificationName";
```

in your `ViewController viewDidLoad:`

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:kStopMusicNotificationName object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        [self.startingMusic stop];
    }];
```

and when you need to stop music:

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:kStopMusicNotificationName object:nil];
```